# Loading Dynamic Views in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview

I am writing an iPhone app in which I need to load xib files dynamically onto the view. I have  4 such scenarios, which I am loading in my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and the corresponding view as per the condition check must get loaded dynamically. The code seems to be running fine  as I am getting no compile time errors but  I am getting a linker error  `linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` in either of 3 files(depending on the dynamic scenario). The external libs have imported into the project only once.Now I am planning to use a `Singleton` of the library.

The dynamic view that has been loaded contains,external libraries of an external hardware device.

I have resolved the same issue in Android by setting the `setContentView(R.layout.as_per_condition);` content view as per condition. I was wondering if there could be any similar approach for this in iOS.

As, Apple reviews every code from memory point of view also, I am bit worried ,Is there any better way to resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using some framework classes, but didn't import necessary headers in your classes. That's why you can get linker errors. As for dynamic views, could you please clarify the question or post some code?